# Watermarking: Display the same text on multiple parts of the image

Tags: php

I want to add a text to a image. The text should be displayed in multiple areas of the image (not just one).

For example I want to watermark with a text stack. Stack should be displayed in the image at least 8 times in different areas in the image.

I just learned about `imagestring()` and `imagettftext()`, but these two only displays my text on a single spot.

Image is not fixed size, so i cannot specify exact and multiple location in advance. It should work on all sizes of images

```
<?php
/*
image.php
*/
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imgPath = 'olximage.jpg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$string = "stack overflow";
$fontSize = 3;
$x = 15;
$y = 185;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
$x = 15;
$y = 175;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, why dont you use these 8 times?

Comment: as for as I know it will create 8 different images

Comment: No it won't if you use these with the same image resource and for example different coordinates.

Comment: @Gennadiy Litvinyuk thanks it works, but image is not fixed size, so i cannot specify exact location. this is all  sizes of images

Comment: You can get height of the image and calculate how many times you can put your text on it eg. (height / font size)

Comment: @Gennadiy Litvinyuk Thanks. I will try it

Comment: Please provide some code, it is impossible to give you more precise answer without seeing your code.

Comment: @Gennadiy Litvinyuk I have updated my post with code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101049/discussion-between-gennadiy-litvinyuk-and-sugumar-venkatesan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
<?php
/*
image.php
*/

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imgPath = 'olximage.jpg';

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$string = "stack overflow";

$fontSize = 3;

$imageHeight = imagesy($image);
$distanceY = 10;
$maxImageStrings = max(8, $imageHeight / $distanceY);

$x = 15;    

for ($i = 0; $i < $maxImageStrings; $i++) {
    $y = $i * $distanceY;
    imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
}

imagejpeg($image);
```

You can finetune calculations for your needs.

Comment: Thanks bro I will try it

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Imagick extension](http://php.net/manual/book.imagick.php) for same. If you want to go with this then follow detail:

**PHP:**

```
// Create objects
$image = new Imagick('image.png');
$watermark = new Imagick();

// Watermark text
$text = 'Copyright';

// Create a new drawing palette
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$watermark->newImage(140, 80, new ImagickPixel('none'));

// Set font properties
$draw->setFont('Arial');
$draw->setFillColor('grey');
$draw->setFillOpacity(.5);

// Position text at the top left of the watermark
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTHWEST);

// Draw text on the watermark
$watermark->annotateImage($draw, 10, 10, 0, $text);

// Position text at the bottom right of the watermark
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTHEAST);

// Draw text on the watermark
$watermark->annotateImage($draw, 5, 15, 0, $text);

// Repeatedly overlay watermark on image
for ($w = 0; $w < $image->getImageWidth(); $w += 140) {
    for ($h = 0; $h < $image->getImageHeight(); $h += 80) {
        $image->compositeImage($watermark, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $w, $h);
    }
}

// Set output image format
$image->setImageFormat('png');

// Output the new image
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

although there are plenty of command-line examples to be found on the [ImageMagick website](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_text), so that is where we shall begin.

Comment: Thanks your solution may be working but this needs me to install imagick what i am using is a shared hosting, and may changed anywhere.